# Timout exeption error with my selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors

this is my code

```
import mouse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from time import sleep
import random


email= 'email'
password= "password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
time.sleep(1)
enter_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
enter_email.send_keys(email)
print('email entered')
time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
enter_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
enter_password.send_keys(password)
print('password entered')
time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
enter_password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print('logged in succesfull')
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
search = 'what i want to search'
search_for_question = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'search')))
search_for_question.send_keys(search)
```

when I run this I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EL127032\PycharmProjects\quora\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    search_for_question = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'search')))
  File "C:\Users\EL127032\PycharmProjects\quora\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I don't know how i am able to fix this problem. i already searched google stack overflow and youtube. But wasn't able to fix this problem. Someone please help me. (note i don't have a lot of experience with this kind of scripts so please make your explanation dummy proof)

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using a wrong locator there.
Just use this instead and it will work fine:

```
search_input_css_selector = 'input.q-input'

search_for_question = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, search_input_css_selector)))
search_for_question.send_keys(search)
```

It's also better to use visibility expected condition rather than just an existence since when the element is found existing on the page it is normally still not completely finished building, it will take some more short time while trying clicking on the element or sending it a text right at that moment will not work properly.

Comment: when i do this is still get the same error. Do you understand why?

Comment: Try using `presence_of_element_located` as previously instead of `visibility_of_element_located` and please let me know if it helped

Comment: With the same timeout error? can you add a screenshot of the web page state when this error occurs?

Comment: im sorry typed something wrong works now.

Comment: thanks for your help mate. apprichate it a lot